# Git status get changed files inside new directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I set up the ignoring filters throug `.gitignore` file. So, for `git status` command I see this:

```
1.c
2.c
3.cpp
4.cpp
aaa/
```

But I want to see full list of filtered files of `aaa` subdirectory instead of `aaa/` for to be sure what my `.gitignore` are configured correctly. Can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do a,

```
git status <directory-name>/
```

Since a directory will show only if it is untracked, you can also do,

```
git status -u
```

You can also pass mode with this option, which defaults to `all`.

`all` shows individual files in untracked directories.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the -u option, nice shortcut

Answer (score 1):

You can force git to show you the files that were changed in that directory by running :

```
git status aaa/
```

Be aware that the trailing `/` is important here

Comment: but `aaa` contains `bbb` which contains `ccc`. It is unconvenient to do the same for each subdirectory recursively.

Comment: Then you should use -u